# I failed a reopen-vote audit which only had minor improvements

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits

I just failed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30039334/revisions) audit in reopen-vote reviews. It just had some grammar fixes and a little cleanup, so no major improvement whatsoever.

Why did I fail this audit?

Comment: You failed 'cause it is currently open and you suggested that it stay closed. You're not independently assessing the question to see whether the question should be open or not.

Comment: But I thought re-open votes were case once a question was closed and then edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Ben mentions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293721/i-failed-a-reopen-vote-audit-which-only-had-minor-improvements#comment190525_293721), the answer to your "Why did I fail" question is pretty cut and dry:

> You failed 'cause it is currently open and you suggested that it stay closed. You're not independently assessing the question to see whether the question should be open or not.

In the reopen queue, you are assessing the quality of the question (in its current state) and whether it should be open or closed.  That's all you really should be doing because anything else shouldn't matter.

Looking at an edit that may (or may not) have triggered the question getting put into reopen queue and deciding whether the question should be reopened based on the edit is not fair to the post.  How do you know the edit was important to being reopened?  Maybe the question should have been reopened before the edit or should never have been closed in the first place?  Maybe the question was almost perfect and just needed a minor edit to be reopen-worthy.

Comment: I agree, but this makes me wonder why we're shown the edit diff in the queue if we're not supposed to use it.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom I think it can be useful when an edit kicks the post into the review queue, but only as a secondary means of evaluation.  When I do look a reopen items, I tend to try to make my initial decision based only on what I am reading.  Then I look at everything else to see if there is a reason to change my mind.